# Problem of missing functions when I want to run UI5 app in SAP Cloud Platform

Tags: cloud, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I have deployed one `SAPUI5` template `worklist` app in SAP Cloud Platform and when I try to run it in the cloud platform via the link that is accessible in cockpit I get the following error.

It is strange for me as I can run it in `WEBIDE` and `ABAP Repository`.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o.getLogonSystem(...).isTrial is not a function

[image: Error in SAP cloud platform when running the app]

Comment: too less information. some code at the least is required to understand the issue.

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi It is not related to code, it is related to IDE and environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function must only be available after library-preload is done. Make sure that you are not declaring the libraries in init section.

Comment: I don't declare or revoke this function at all. And that is the problem. It seems this is an internal function of the SAPUI5 and it is not defined in their Cloud version of the UI5 library.

Comment: So invoke all libraries, the same way as sapwebide does, make use of developer tools

Comment: It must be done automatically. I don't have to invoke any libraries. That is not the solution. It must invoke a library when it is needed. It has a lazy binding mechanism.

Comment: What is the version of SAPUI5 on the cloud and when you run via WEB IDE? You can check via "sap.ui.version".